# ActivityNotFoundException but i've declared in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, activitynotfoundexception

my error is

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11101): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.hellolinear/java.text.Normalizer$Form}; 
have you declared this activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?
```

but in my manifest code is:

```
  <activity android:name=".Form"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter/>
    </activity>
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: post your complete manifest code

Comment: Can you post the intent and packages imported?

Answer (score 1):

If non of above works, then

1. uninstall app from your device
2. restart eclipse( if you are using it, otherwise other `IDE`)
3. clean your project

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the activity is in the root package. Otherwise mention the package path while declaring in manifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.smstracking.MainActivity"
           >
        </activity>
```

Comment: the activity is in the root package :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you the package name is incorrect? Try specifying the full package name like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.hellolinear.Form"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter/>
</activity>
```

The correct way to this, however, would be to add the package name like this tou your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hellolinear"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

at least one activity must contain with **intent filter** that contain **action as action.MAIN** and **category** as **Launcher** as per my knowledge.Hope this helps as you haven't provided the intent filter in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <activity android:name="your package name.Your Activity Name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Package name is not written correctly. Your Code:

```
<activity 
   android:name=".Form"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter/>
</activity>
```

Instead of above, write this:

```
<activity 
    android:name="your package name.Form"    // eg: android:name="com.example.myapp.Form"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter/>
    </activity>
```